# Reshaping dataframe with pandas - access to nested columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I want to reshape a dataframe that holds IDs, Features, Feature Codes, and the respective Values for each Feature Code.
Every feature can have several attributes, and only if there is a value in this attribute, then it is listed as a row in the table. The values are the absolute numbers, how often this feature is represented in my object (ID).

I know all possible attributes:

e.g. feature color: ["warm", "cold"]
e.g. feature number: ["0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-100"]

It looks like this:

| ID | Feature | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID01 | color | warm | 5 |
| ID01 | color | cold | 3 |
| ID01 | number | 0-10 | 1 |
| ID01 | number | 21-30 | 2 |
| ID01 | number | 41-100 | 7 |
| ID02 | color | warm | 9 |
| ID02 | number | 0-10 | 2 |
| ID02 | number | 11-20 | 2 |
| ID02 | number | 31-40 | 1 |

Now I wanted to reshape it, so that the IDs are unique and the cells hold the values (last column) for the combination of feature and attribute.

It should look like this:
(Instead of NaN in the end I want to have, but I can fix that later)

| ID | color_warm | color_cold | number_0-10 | number_11-20 | number_21-30 | number_31-40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID01 | 5 | 3 | 1 | NaN | 2 | NaN |
| ID02 | 9 | NaN | 2 | 2 | NaN | 1 |

| ID | number_41-100 |
| --- | --- |
| ID01 | 7 |
| ID02 | NaN |

I used the following code:

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', delimiter=";")`

`df_new = pd.df.pivot(index='ID', columns=['Feature', 'Attribute'], values='Value')`

Now I have the problem, that it creates a combination of feature and attribute, so that I don't know how to access and reorganize them. Instead of a column ['color', 'warm'] and ['color', cold'] I would like to have color_warm and color_cold. Because many functions don't allow lists as parameter for columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["tmp"] = df["Feature"] + "_" + df["Attribute"]

df_out = df.pivot(index="ID", columns="tmp", values="Value")
df_out.columns.name = None
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
     ID  color_cold  color_warm  number_0-10  number_11-20  number_21-30  number_31-40  number_41-100
0  ID01         3.0         5.0          1.0           NaN           2.0           NaN            7.0
1  ID02         NaN         9.0          2.0           2.0           NaN           1.0            NaN
```